# How display only one child id on PHP?

Tags: php

I have something like this:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $cat):
$blog = $a->getSpend("WHERE hide = 0 && parent_id = $cat->id  ORDER BY id DESC");
?>
```

`parent_id = $cat->id` this one displays all the child ids but I need to display only one specific child id, stuck here and need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only on "blog" for each category, consider using "LIMIT" on you query:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $cat): ?>
    <?php
        $blog = $a->getSpend("WHERE hide = 0 && parent_id = $cat->id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Yeah it's cool thing but in this parent id i have 5 categories from which i want to show category thats id is 5. How can i show only this id not others?